# Error:Line 924: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I am trying to solve the leetcode problem [maximum profit scheduling](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-profit-in-job-scheduling/). I think there is no mistake in my logic but I don't understand why I am getting the above error.I have spent quite some time on it trying to understand the error  I have run it on my local ide and I get a segmentation fault but I wasn't able to spot where I am going out of bounds of any data structure in my code. I am attaching the code snippet below .kindly help me in understanding my mistake.

```
 class Solution {
 public:
 typedef pair<pair<int,int>,int> ppi;
 static bool comparator(ppi a,ppi b)
{
    if(a.first.second<b.first.second)
        return true;
    if(a.first.second==b.first.second)
        return a.second<b.second;
    return false;
}
int jobScheduling(vector<int>& startTime, vector<int>& endTime, vector<int>& profit) {
    if(startTime.size()==0) return 0;
    int n=profit.size();
    vector<ppi> in;
    vector<int> dp(0,n);
    int i=0,j=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {dp[i]=profit[i];
    }
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {in.push_back({{startTime[i],endTime[i]},profit[i]});
    }

  sort(in.begin(),in.end(),comparator);
   for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=i-1;j>=0;j--)
        {
            if(in[j].first.second<=in[i].first.first)
            { dp[i]=max(in[i].second+dp[j],dp[i-1]);
              break;
            }
         
        }
        dp[i]=max(dp[i],dp[i-1]);
    }
    
    return dp[n-1];  
   }
};
```

Comment: `vector<int> dp(0,n);` This creates a vector of size **0**. Perhaps you meant to do `vector<int> dp(n);`. Or even better in this context: `vector<int> dp = profit;`.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is precisely what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: @TrebledJ thanks sir. I didn't look at this silly mistake. this fixed the problem.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks for the valuable suggestion. I will learn how to use a debugger .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This'll pass, similarly O(N Log N) runtime and O(N) space using map:

```
// The following block might trivially improve the exec time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto __optimize__ = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(NULL);
    std::cout.tie(NULL);
    return 0;
}();

// Most of headers are already included;
// Can be removed;
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>

const static struct Solution {
    using SizeType = std::int_fast32_t;
    static int jobScheduling(
        const std::vector<int>& start_times,
        const std::vector<int>& end_times,
        const std::vector<int>& profits
    ) {
        const SizeType start_length = std::size(start_times);
        std::vector<std::vector<SizeType>> jobs;

        for (SizeType index = 0; index < start_length; index++) {
            jobs.emplace_back(std::vector<SizeType> {
                end_times[index],
                start_times[index],
                profits[index]
            });
        }

        std::sort(std::begin(jobs), std::end(jobs));
        map<SizeType, SizeType> job_profit_map = {{0, 0}};

        for (const auto& job : jobs) {
            const SizeType curr = std::prev(job_profit_map.upper_bound(job[1]))->second + job[2];

            if (curr > std::rbegin(job_profit_map)->second) {
                job_profit_map[job[0]] = curr;
            }
        }

        return std::rbegin(job_profit_map)->second;
    }
};
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-profit-in-job-scheduling/discuss) where you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including low-complexity algorithms and asymptotic [runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.